# iPhone Animation: how to anti-alias?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, antialiasing

I was looking at some animations in my iPhone app and felt like it was kind of ugly. And then I undertsood it: it just doesn't animate through subpixel states.

So, in case I use usual +beginAnimations/+commitAnimations, moving some stuff just a few pixels look "jumpy". How can I avoid it? Are there any flags to make it animate through float coords or whatever?

Just to give you an idea of what I have and what I'm looking for, please refer to the picture:

[alt text http://www.ptoing.net/subpixel_aa.gif](http://www.ptoing.net/subpixel_aa.gif)

Thanks in advance,
Anton

Comment: Can you update the link to your picture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's funny, but I found that UIImageView animate its content **using** aniti-aliasing, while edges of the view are not anti-aliased (hard). It seems to be because UIView itself should maintain the same bounds, while subpixel rendering might add to the bound a bit.

So, I ended up just putting an image with some transparent space around the picture, and it all went smooth.

Just don't let UIView cut its contents for you :)

Comment: here is simple way to avoid without any code at all http://www.techpaa.com/2012/06/avoiding-view-edge-antialiasing.html

Comment: @jeeva This might be a simple solution, but it does entail a noticeable performance hit (as mentioned in the [Apple iOS Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html))

Comment: @adamjansch i will agree it has impact on performance it depends on how much rendering your view has.

Answer (score 1):

You can try deriving the item you're animating from a custom UIView that overrides its `drawRect` method and sets anti-aliasing on for it then lets the parent draw into it. Something along the lines of:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)area
{
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSaveGState(context);
  CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);
  CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
  [super drawRect:area];
  // We have to turn it back off since it's not saved in graphic state.
  CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, false);
  CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

On the other hand, it might be too late in the rendering pipeline by the time you get here, so you may have to end up rolling your own animation scheme that lets you have full control over pixel-positioning.

Comment: I tried this. Seems that drawRect is not called while animating, as animation is done level below (I guess).

Comment: Yes, I thought it might be too late. You could try the same trick down at the CALayer level, but my guess is the only way around it is to roll your own sprite mover.

Answer (score 0):

Per Jeeva's comment above, you can make UIView edges render with Anti-aliasing by settings the following option in the info.plist to YES.

```
Renders with edge antialiasing
```

Here is the link Jeeva pointed to:

http://www.techpaa.com/2012/06/avoiding-view-edge-antialiasing.html